# Regex to find string A only before string B occurs - Python

Tags: python, regex, string

What I am looking to do is match a string "A" which appears multiple times in a text file, but I would like to match it only before string "B" appears.

For example - the text file may read:

```
(cell = "33"
Level = "2"

(
cGG Track
sample = "ThisSample"
Level = "201" )

(cGG Track
sample = "ThisOtherSample)
)
```

I would like to match the value of level, but only before the line "sample = " "" occurs. So in the above example, I would like to match "2".

If the examples reads:

```
(
ParamFigit = "3e"

(cGggTrack
sample = "ex"
Level = "3")
)
```

I would not want level at all, and I would just set it as 0.

I use:

```
levelRegex = re.compile(r'Level = "(.*)"')
levelMatch = levelRegex.findall(MyText)
```

Which I use to get the value of level. The issue I'm having is that I'm getting the wrong one. I can't say just get the first match of the regex, because it will not always happen before "sample = "x""

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: and if several level values occur before "sample", which one do you want? The first, the last, all of them?

Comment: A very crude workaround: call `split("sample")` on your file text, and then run your regex on the first element of the returned array (all `levels` in this element are guaranteed to occur before the first mention of `sample`). The issue Casimir mentions is pertinent though.

Comment: As my files exist, there can only ever be one level value before the later sample values. That's why my first instinct was to match only if before sample.

Comment: This should do it. `/Level = "(\d+)"[\n\s\(\)\w]+(?=sample)/g` where $1 contains your numeric data.

Comment: @Redu `sample` goes after `Level`, not before. And lookbehind assertion `(?<=sample....)(Level....)` should be of fixed length in its look behind part, so it's inappropriate.

Comment: @user3159253 in the above code you have two samples...in the given regex each one matches the previous Level value. so the first sample (sample = "ThisSample") matches 2 and the second (sample = "ThisOtherSample") matches 201. Is this not what you wanted..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract data using combination of regex lookahead and lookbehind.

Your regex will be

```
(?<=Level = )\"((?:\d+\.)?\d+)\".*?(?=sample = \")
```

Example:

```
import re

with open('data.txt', 'r') as fp:
    data = fp.read()

    rx = re.compile(r"(?<=Level = )\"((?:\d+\.)?\d+)\".*?(?=sample = \")",
                    re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL)

    result = [int(num) for num in rx.findall(data)]

    print(result)
```

Based on sample content you provided in post, it will print:

```
[2, 201]
```

Comment: Thanks everyone! I will try some of these out and see what happens :)

Comment: This one works great - how would I edit it to work with floats? say for a value of "Level = 0.2" ?

Comment: Awesome! Not to make it even more complicated, but - I've also run into a few negative values!  "Level = -0.2"  - any ideas? :)

Comment: ahh, Your original question has been answered so II'd suggest you to open another post and put together your thoughts about what else you may want.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the file line by line:

```
import re
from itertools import takewhile

with open('yourfile') as fh:
    [print(re.match(r'^Level = "([^"]*)"',i).group(1)) for i in takewhile((lambda x: 'sample' not in x), fh) if 'Level' in i]
```

If you slurp the whole file (Akshat Mahajan's way) in a string s:

```
m = re.match(r'^Level = "([^"]*)"(?m)', s.split('sample', 1)[0])
if m: print m.group(1)
```

"Pure" regex way (ugly): *from the start of the string, reach the first "Level =" occurrence at the start of a line and forbids the word "sample"*

```
m = re.match(r'^[^sL]*(?:(?:\B[sL]|s(?!ample\b)|(?<=.)L|L(?!evel =))[^sL]*)*Level = "([^"]*)"', s)
if m: print m.group(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If Python can do assertions, this seems to work.

`(?s)^(?:(?!\b(?:Level|sample)\s*=\s*".*?").)*\bLevel\s*=\s*"(.*?)"(?:(?!\b(?:Level|sample)\s*=\s*".*?").)*\bsample\s*=\s*".*?"`

*Level value in capture group 1*

Expanded

```
 (?s)                          # Dot-all modifier
 ^                             # BOS
 (?:                           # Not Level or Sample
      (?! \b (?: Level | sample ) \s* = \s* " .*? " )
      . 
 )*
 \b Level \s* = \s*            # Level
 "
 ( .*? )                       # (1), Value
 "
 (?:                           # Not Level or Sample
      (?! \b (?: Level | sample ) \s* = \s* " .*? " )
      . 
 )*
 \b sample \s* = \s* " .*? "   # Sample
```

Output

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 64 ) 
(cell = "33"
Level = "2"

(
cGG Track
sample = "ThisSample"  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 23 , len 1 ) 
2
```